# Regex to restrict certain characters

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

is there someone that can help me come up with a regex that restricts these characters `!@#$%^&*()_-`? Most of the post here and google lead me to regex that allow a prescribed set of characters and I cannot seem to have much luck coming up with my own.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
After some tries came up with below and seems to work so no further help needed:

```
"Has restricted-characters_?".replace(/^\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\‌​(|\)|\_|\-|`|\?/, " ")
```

Comment: Please post what have you  tried so far, and some sample string your regex should match.

Comment: Where is the sample input? what is the expected output? what have you tried to achive that? What error/unexpected result do you get?

Comment: What does to “to restrict certain characters” mean? And why must you use a regex to do it?

Comment: Nevermind all, I've come up with `/^\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\_|\-|\`|\?/.test("Has restricted-characters_?")` and running some tests

Comment: Why is this tagged with two languages?

Comment: @Amy The regex will be used both front-end (Javascript) and back-end (C#).

Comment: @Morgs because the regex depends *on the language*.  You may not necessarily be able to use the same regex in both places.  It is a reasonable question.

Comment: Also if anyone is really indeed willing to help. I can't seem to get the _ and ? removed when I `"Has restricted-characters_?".replace(/^\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\_|\-|`|\?/, " ")` the results is `"Has restricted characters_?"`

Comment: Ok figured I needed to add the `/g` indicator at the end of the expression... @Amy sorry just got put off with all these questions after asking a question.Thanks all anyway...

Comment: "H@a#s$ re%stri^cted& -characters_?".replace(/[!@#$%^&*()_\-?]/g, "") is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
rgx = (/[\^!@#$%^&*()_?-]/g);
test = str => console.log(str ,str.match(rgx))

test('qwerty')
test('!qwerty')
test('q@werty')
test('qw#erty')
test('qwer$ty')
test('qwert%y')
test('qwerty^')
test('qwertyq&werty')
test('qwertyqwe*rty')
test('qwertyqwert(y')
test('qwertyqwerty)')
test('qwertyqwertyq_wertyqwerty')
test('qwertyqwertyqwe?rtyqwerty')
test('qwertyqwertyqwert-yqwerty')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[^!@#$%^&*()_?-]
```

will do for all the characters. You've got to put them in **[ ]** with a **^** in front.

Note to escape the **-** with a **\** (Ex: [^!@#$%^&*\-()_?]) or put the **-** in the very end.

This works, you can try it in here,

https://regexr.com/